# Combining multiple similar functions into one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched through StackOverflow for what I regard as a basic issue, but I could not find any relevant threads. Mainly because I feel like I am searching for the wrong keywords.

I would like to know how the summarize the next bit into as few lines of code as possible. When you click on 'link-#', it loads the content from the hidden div 'more-#' (where the # in more could be any number, but is the same as the number in link-#.) Right now I have this:

```
jQuery("#link-1").click(function(){
    jQuery('#more').hide().html($('#more-1').html()).fadeIn(400)
});
jQuery("#link-2").click(function(){
    jQuery('#more').hide().html($('#more-2').html()).fadeIn(400)
});
jQuery("#link-3").click(function(){
    jQuery('#more').hide().html($('#more-3').html()).fadeIn(400)
});
```

etc.

I assume it should be something like below, but obviously it's not the correct way.

```
jQuery("#link" + NUMBER ).click(function(){
    jQuery('#more').hide().html($('#more-' + this.NUMBER).html()).fadeIn(400)
});
```

I bet you guys know exactly how to deal with this! Thank you for your help.

Best regards,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them all the same class name and then add the attribute "data-num" and then:

```
jQuery(".className").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var html = jQuery('#more' + $this.attr('data-num')).html();
    jQuery('#more').hide().html(html);
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<a class='className' data-num='1'>Link</a>
<div id='more1'></div>
<div id='more'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A preferable approach is to group these items by giving them the same class, and use a `data-*` attribute to identify the associated element:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".show-more").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    jQuery('#more').hide().html($(target).html()).fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

```css
#moreItems {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="show-more" data-target="#more-1">Show More 1</a>
<a href="#" class="show-more" data-target="#more-2">Show More 2</a>
<a href="#" class="show-more" data-target="#more-3">Show More 3</a>
<div id="more"></div>
<div id="moreItems">
  <div id="more-1">Here are the details 1</div>
  <div id="more-2">Here are the details 2</div>
  <div id="more-3">Here are the details 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe is better approach is to put a selector in a `data-*` attribute like: `<a href="#" class="showMore" data-target="#more1">Show More 1</a>`, Bootstrap (2 ou 3, can't remember) uses it in some components